# listview or listactivity in another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

can anyone explain me in detail how to create ListView (or smth like that) in fragment_main.xml that would take only part of application, not new activity. Like activity in activity.

This is my application layout and I want to create list in tab called"megstamiausi" how do i do that?

[image]

Comment: You want to know how to add a `ListView` in the layout of the `Fragment`?

Comment: can you post your fragment_main.xml  code ?, each fragment tab has a separate class.

Comment: Code - https://github.com/Declawler/FoodOrderApp_Android
Yes, I want something like ListView in fragment or activity in activity (i dont know how to call it). I need list in second tab..

Comment: You can try ListFragment.

Comment: Been thinking of that, but its supported from android api 11..

Edit: sorry, it does support.. Gonna stick with it